# Author name/year cited inline (According to Aaaaa (2013)...)

Tags: biblatex

How can I cite author (e.g. John Doe) with year *inline* following this format:

> According to Doe (2013) LaTeX is very powerful...

I am using `biblatex` with `style=authoryear` & `backend=biber`.

After trying some commands and google search it did not worked.
But to make citations in the end of text citations I am using `\parencite{Doe2013}` and it works as I need

> .....(Doe, 2013)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for `\textcite`.

For all the cite commands have a look at §3.8 *Citation Commands* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

MWE

```
\documentclass[british, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}% to patch the editor macros
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{testart,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor and William Riter},
  title         = {A Very Interesting Article},
  journal       = {Journal of Articles},
  volume        = {7},
  page          = {1-5},
  date          = {2013},
}
@book{testbook,
  author        = {Walter Ordsmith},
  editor        = {Eddie Ditor},
  title         = {The Work},
  subtitle      = {Subtitle},
  date          = {1983},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
  Text \textcite{testbook} bla.

  Comparison of \verb|*cite| commands:
  \begin{tabular}{rl}
    \verb|\cite|      & \cite{testart}\\
    \verb|\parencite| & \parencite{testart}\\
    \verb|\textcite|  & \textcite{testart}\\
  \end{tabular}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Moewe, but that command gives me the key **Doe2013** and not **Doe (2013)** as I need :)

Comment: yes it is! I used your example above running it in my texmkr and the output is like yours. But then I changed the key **testbook** to **Or83** (author and year of that same reference) and then the output has the format I got with my project (the reason for my post here). Do you know if the issue is addressed to some type of config? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes the change was in doc and .bib file. Texmaker 3.4. Frequently I run apt-get update so I think it is updated. Tex system is "vanilla" TexLive (2012).

Comment: biblatex V. 28797 (2.5) and biber V. 28798 (1.5)

Comment: in my project just replaced a citation key **AuthorYear** by **Author** and it gave my the output I need :D yay! just do not understand why it happens. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Very strange indeed, but if it works now. Now that your problem is resolved, it would be a good idea to delete unnecessary comments under this answer (e.g. those concerning the version numbers of your software).